# Degree equivalence between Argentina and Europe

Tags: masters, funding, degree

I graduated as an Electronic Engineer at University of Buenos Aires (UBA), Argentina. I want to apply to scholarships to undertake a **Master's course** in Europe, and I'm often asked the level of my degree. Here is where things get confusing.

At UBA we have somewhat unorthodox course durations and syllabuses. While in most Argentinian universities an undergraduate course  has a duration of 3 to 5 years, at UBA courses last 6 years (when passing every single subject at once and not lagging behind). Additionally, at Engineering School we have some subjects that would correspond to MSc level abroad (in the last 2 years we can choose specific subjects about advanced topics we want to specialize in, while general engineering topics are covered during the first 4 years). We also have to carry out either a research project or a professional one before graduating, and then write a thesis about it.

What would be the European equivalence for this degree? I've seen a few, but I'm really not sure which one I should choose when applying for a scholarship abroad. The ones that I think would be good choices are:

- BSc
- BEng
- MSc
- MEng
- MEngSc

As far as I understand after doing some research about this, I think the one that looks the most similar to my degree would be **BEng**. I also think that putting MSc could be detrimental to my application (even if the degree has a Master's degree level), because I want to pursue a Master's abroad and not a PhD.

Which one would you suggest is the right one to choose?

Comment: Note that in the UK the honours suffix ("Hons") denotes that you didn't fail any courses during the degree, nothing more special than that. But why can't you just put the actual name of your degree?

Comment: @astronat Because I'm offered a list with degree types, so I have to choose one option among those in the drop-down list. BTW thanks for the observation regarding "Hons"!

Comment: I see, in that case it's probably a good idea to get in touch with whatever university/organisation you are applying to, explain the situation and see which option they suggest. I'm not an engineer, but to my mind an MSc is a one year taught Master's whereas an MEng probably indicates a four year "integrated Master's" (common in UK STEM; you do 3 years of BSc equivalent plus the Master's year, so you don't get a separate BSc), so quite different degrees. I won't post this as answer yet, as I expect someone with more knowledge of Argentina/ engineering will have a better one.

Comment: @astronat possibly at your institution, but that’s certainly not generically true.

Comment: @astronat I did Hons in my UK degree and it means doing more credits compared to an ordinary degree, **nothing** to do with not failing a course.

Comment: @SolarMike ah, I only commented that because that's how it was at my university and for a number of friends at other unis. Overall it still seems OP should get in touch with the scholarship they are applying to to determine which option to choose on the form.